# Fitting a Velux blind to a modified window

Tags: windows, blinds

I would like to fit a standard blind to my Velux window (model GGL-7).  However, it appears to have been fitted for a non-standard type of blind: there are thin wooden rails on each side, and an extra piece of wood with metal brackets at the top.  The extra parts have been painted over, and look like they would be difficult to remove without damaging the frame and/or glass (although I think I could remove the two metal brackets, as they're just secured with screws).

The top of the window (with the opening handle) is on the right-hand side of the attached picture.

Is it possible to fit a standard Velux blind to this window without removing the extra parts?  I'm concerned that there might not be room for the side rails, and that it may not be possible to screw the blind cartridge to the top of the window with the extra bit of wood in place.

[image: Velux window with extra fittings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now fitted the blind, and both the top piece and the side rails needed to be removed.

- the top part was replaced by the blind cartridge, which fits flush to the frame
- the side rails, while narrow enough to allow the new rails to be fitted, fouled the inside edge of the blind cartridge.

In the end all three parts were easy to remove as they had been fitted with short nails which pulled free of the frame with little force.